# Using ng-href with geo: Uri in Cordova does not work

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, geo, angularjs-ng-href

I am trying to use the geo: uri in Cordova.
It works when I do something like:

```
<a href="geo:0,0q=12345+jefferson+st">link1</a>
```

but if I do something like with angular:

```
<a ng-href="{{location}}">{{location}}>link2</a>
```

and

```
location = "geo:0,0q=12345+jefferson+st";
```

it will not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly add `geo:` to Angular's whitelist using a regular expression using `$compileProvider`. Otherwise Angular will prefix a non-whitelisted href URLs with `unsafe:` when using a unrecognized url by `$compileProvider`.

**Config**

```
var app = angular.module( 'app', [] )
.config( ['$compileProvider', function( $compileProvider ){   
        $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|geo):/);
}]);
```

Hopefully this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: Ya thank you! I actually figured it out a few hours before you responded but you nailed it!